# Show $\lim_{x\to +\infty} \int_1^x \frac 1{x^\alpha+t^\beta}\;\mathrm{d} t = 0$.

Tags: improper-integrals

Show that
$$
\lim_{x\to +\infty} \int_1^x \frac 1{x^\alpha+t^\beta}\;\mathrm{d} t = 0
$$
if $\alpha, \beta >0$ and $\max{\alpha, \beta} > 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\beta >1$. Let $\epsilon >0$ and choose $M$ such that $\int_M^{\infty} \frac 1 {x^{\alpha}+t^{\beta}} dt \leq \int_M^{\infty} \frac 1 {t^{\beta}} dt <\epsilon$. Note that  $\int_1^{M} \frac 1 {x^{\alpha}+t^{\beta}} dt \leq \frac {M-1} {x^{\alpha}} \to 0$ so $\int_1^{M} \frac 1 {x^{\alpha}+t^{\beta}} dt  <\epsilon$ for  $x$ sufficiently large.

Next consider the case when $\alpha >1$. Here we have the obvious bound $\frac {x-1} {x^{\alpha}}$ which tends to $0$.

Comment: In your first case, does $\beta > 1$ make any difference? Why we need that?

Comment: Very much. $\int_M^{\infty} \frac  1{t^{\beta}} dt=\infty$ if $\beta \leq 1$. @WeiZhong